# Puppeteer-sharp: page is crashed from browser.NewPageAsync()

Tags: c#, browser, puppeteer, chromium, puppeteer-sharp

I am using example code from Puppeteer-sharp but faced timeout error when calling `browser.NewPageAsync()`. Then I turned on `Devtools` and saw the page is crashed in Chromium.

```cs
var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();
await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync();
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = true,
    Devtools = true
});

// page is crashed in Chromium and timeout after 5 mins
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

await page.GoToAsync("http://www.google.com");

await page.DisposeAsync();
await browser.DisposeAsync();
```

*PuppeteerSharp version is 4.0.0

Comment: You should always dispose `browser` and `page` objects at the end of execution. Add the respective `Dispose()` calls and see if that helps. I faced such issue once as I wasn't disposing my `page` objects.

Comment: @YashGupta, yes, forgot to put to here. Thanks for remind and help.

Answer (score 1):

Should be due to PuppeteerSharp requires to run on Linux system in Azure (which can download and install Chromium by coding). If want to test on Windows, need to pre-install Chrome/Chromium and add `ExecutablePath` in `LaunchOptions`

```cs
// DEBUG: for running on local
ExecutablePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
```

Please share if you have other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of other things that you can try out during your troubleshooting:

- Make sure to dispose all the pages & browser being opened (as I suggested in comments).
- Try adding the `--full-memory-crash-report` flag (& other flags related to Crash-handling) in your arguments to get more insight as in what's going wrong with your execution. You can literally take a mini-dump of your execution to understand the issue. The entire list of Chromium flags can be found here: [Chromium Command Line Flags](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)
- Make sure nothing is going wrong with Garbage Collection. Since it's just a sample code, you'll have to make sure yourself that you're adding in all the necessary code required for a clean/optimised execution.